# Is it possible to avoid to load some assembly loading into the `AppDomain`?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain

I need to load `SomeMixedAssembly.dll` into the additional domain (i.e. it is not the main domain) and unload that domain after finishing the task. Also the `SomeMixedAssembly.dll` loads the `SomeMixedAssembly_2.dll` which is necessary for its work. Both assemblies are mixed and written not by me. It is not a problem, but the problem is the `SomeMixedAssembly.dll` loads the `SomeMixedAssembly_2.dll` into the *main domain* also.

Is it possible to avoid to load some assembly loading into the main `AppDomain`?

Comment: You would need to create your own proxy that handles communication between the default domain and your created domain. That proxy is then loaded in its own domain and is a wrapper around the types defined in `SomeMixedAssembly`. Do not leak any of the types in `SomeMixedAssembly` directly through the proxy.  That should stop `SomeMixedAssembly` from being loaded in the default domain and also its dependencies.

Comment: To clarify Igors comment, the assembly is not loading itself into the main domain. *You* are by copying an object from the auxiliary domain to the main domain forcing the type to be loaded there.

Comment: I know about `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` and I use a proxy.  The sample of my "HelloWorld" is here (git repository): https://bitbucket.org/Andrey-Bushman/acadcui/wiki/Home The `SomeMixedAssembly.dll` is `AcCUI.dll` and the `SomeMixedAssembly_2.dll` is `AcDbMgd.dll` in that example.

Comment: I suppose the word "mixed" applies here.  AppDomains are a pure managed concept, they only isolate managed objects.  Any memory allocated by native code in a mixed-mode assembly is not isolated.  It can't be.  The isolation boundary for native code is a *process*.

Comment: @HansPassant, does it mean that *any mixed* assemblies *always* will be loaded into the main `AppDomain` *also*?

Comment: Not the issue.  If I guessed right (why do I have to guess), this is about visibility of memory allocated by native code.  A global variable, so common in C code, is just as global to managed code that runs in another AppDomain.  It is process-global.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can intervene in the process of assembly loading, using for instance, [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event handler. But assemblies usually load lazy on demand and you can not just not to load them and expect that your program will work. Assembly loaded in another AppDomain cannot automatically work as the original one by definition.

But such intervention can be useful if you want to load assembly from unusual place, check some prerequisites or for searching bugs.

Comment: I know about it and I use it, but it doesn't help me. You can see my "Hello World" with this problem here: https://bitbucket.org/Andrey-Bushman/acadcui/wiki/Home

Comment: The only possible reason I could see from your code: Assembly that contains Bushman.AcadCUI.Section class could have direct or chained reference to Acdbmgd.dll. Try to set breakpoint at "ISection section ="  line and check assemblies loaded. Then do step out and check again. If my guess is correct, unwanted assembly loaded in this step. Then, IlSpy or Reflector could help you.

Comment: It happens in the 83 row of the `Program.cs` file.

Comment: Really? At line 83 you call DoWork in taskDomain. Does it mean that at line 39 unwanted assembly is already loaded?

Comment: I didn't notice that Section class declared in you exe, so I correct my guess: the most interesting place is lines 61-68 of Section.cs. Maybe unwanted loading is a result of CustomizationSection constructor code.

Comment: Yes, at line 39 unwanted assembly is already loaded (I see it if I add the registration of the `AssemblyLoad` event of the main domain - it happens at the `83` row of the `Program.cs` file). I too think that the CustomizationSection constructor can be reason of this behaviour, but on the main domain I expected to get the proxy of that instance instead of really called constructor.

Comment: Well, what we have: your exe has no references to non-standard assemblies and it loads unwanted assembly even before it knows what to load (the assembly name is a string). 

I see two possibilities: either .Net Runtime **predicts** its future execution (non-realistic assumption)  or the code that really rinning is different from the code you published. I see, that Output for the project is network share. Maybe deployment doesn't work or you have several different copies of you output files and some different assembly really loaded instead of proper one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126829/discussion-between-olk-and-andrey-bushman).